# how to keep the + when parse url in python3

Tags: python-3.x, http, url

when I use this code to parse the url query parameters, the code auto convert to + to " ":

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parsed_url = urlparse("http://a.com?q=a+b")
    query_params = dict(parse_qsl(parsed_url.query))
    print(query_params.get('q'))
```

why did this happen? is it possible to keep the original +, do not convert.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [URI specification](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html) by W3C, `+`s always denote spaces in a query string:

> Within the query string, the plus sign is reserved as shorthand
> notation for a space. Therefore, real plus signs must be encoded. This
> method was used to make query URIs easier to pass in systems which did
> not allow spaces.

So you must encode literal plus signs into `%2B`s in a query string if you want them to be decoded as such:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parsed_url = urlparse("http://a.com?q=a%2Bb")
    query_params = dict(parse_qsl(parsed_url.query))
    print(query_params.get('q'))
```

This outputs:

```
a+b
```